# View transport request contents without a SAP system?

Tags: abap, transport, sap-basis

Is there a way to access the source code of a SAP transport file without a SAP system?
I have a transport file containing an ABAP report which source code I would like to look at. Not run. Unfortunately, I don't have access to an SAP system at the moment. The SAP NetWeaver ABAP Server Trial Version is not available for download anymore. I thought I could have used this trial server to view the code.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way unless you are an organic binary to text decoder and you know the SAP's binary format that is used.

However [here](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1277788) is an interesting discussion on the topic. The guy mentions `R3Trans` program which I however could not find anywhere. I guess it is a part of an SAP application server installation.

Comment: you should be able to download R3trans from the marketplace. Don't know if it needs any additional libraries, but one could just grab the current kernel package and give it a try.

Comment: As Dirk Trilsbeek writes, there are indeed `CAR` and `SAR` archives with R3Trans in the Service Marketplace to download.

Answer (score 0):

As Jagger indication, R3Trans is indeed a solution.
All executable/complement software can be found from Marketplace

1. SAPCAR binary extractor to "unzip" SAR/CAR archive
2. The SAR archive containing the os depending R3Trans executable.
3. Recent version of R3Trans requires 3 Unicode libraries (.dll on Windows, .so on Linux) that could be obtained from NWRFCSDK, Sapgui installation or Kernel setup: icuuc50.dll, icudt50.dll, icuin50.dll